# How to create report with jasper reports

Tags: odoo

i get this WARNNIG when i create my report with jasper reports
'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

,'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**',

```
import jasper_reports
from openerp import pooler
def jasper_sub_test(cr,uid,ids,data,context=None):
pool=pooler.get_pool(cr,dr)
return{}
jasper_reports.report_jasper('report.decompte_client',
'facturation.attachement',
parser=jasper_sub_test
)






<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<report string="report attachement client" 
        model="facturation.attachement" 
        auto="True" 
        name="decompte_report"
        rml="TrvxFacturation/report/report_attach_client.jrxml"
        id="report_test"
        menu="True"
        />
</data>
```

Comment: Without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we cannot help you.

Comment: some one help me thanks